# MS-Access 2003: Create multiple records from a single form

Tags: forms, ms-access

Can anyone point me to an example of an Access form which can create multiple records (in a single table) based on one form?

To expand: we're recording information about time spent on a project on a given date. We've had a request for a single form that would allow a user to enter data for 5 (or 7) days of a given week on a single form. He/she would pick a week from a calendar control, a project from a listbox, then enter up to 7 numbers for the hours spent that week.

I did check questions 5294128, which doesn't seem applicable, and question 8070706, which seems to imply that this can only be done in VBA (not using the GUI). Any alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: In extreme simplicity, use a datasheet form or else a continuous form. You might consider using a master/detail configuration for this.

Comment: @HK1, thanks. I don't see how a continuous form would work, but (obviously) I'm new to this. Access (2003) help doesn't include any entries for "datasheet form".

Comment: it might be called datasheet view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on these lines should suit. This is an unbound form with a subform.

[image: Form]

You can get the form type from the form wizard

[image]

To work properly, you will need a little code, say:

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sSDate As String
Dim sEDate As String

    sSDate = "#" & Format(Me.txtStartDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"
    sEDate = "#" & Format(Me.txtStartDate + Me.txtNoDays, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DataDate Between " & sSDate _
        & " AND " & sEDate

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

    If rs.RecordCount < Me.txtNoDays Then
        AddRecords sSDate, sEDate
    End If

    Me.DataSubform.Form.RecordSource = sSQL
End Sub



Sub AddRecords(sSDate, sEDate)
''Uses counter table with integers from 0 to
''highest required number
''Another useful table is a calendat table, which would
''save some work here.

    sSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable (DataDate) " _
        & "SELECT AddDate FROM " _
        & "(SELECT " & sSDate _
        & " + [counter.ID] AS AddDate " _
        & "FROM [Counter] " _
        & "WHERE " & sSDate _
        & "+ [counter.ID] Between " & sSDate _
        & " And " & sEDate & ") a " _
        & "WHERE AddDate NOT In (SELECT DataDate FROM MyTable)"

    CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Comment: As I interpret the main program, the AddRecords subroutine actually saves the contents of the form into the DB (the "INSERT INTO" query). What I'm puzzled by is how any of what the user typed connects to the fields on the form. I see "Me.DataSubform.Form.RecordSource = sSQL" in the main program, but nothing in AddRecords refers back to the SubForm to find out what data to save back into the table, confusing me mightily. So where does AddRecords get the data it's inserting? And thanks for the help.

Comment: AddRecords creates records in MyTable for the dates that the user has chosen by entering a start date and a period of days. If the records are not available, AddRecords creates the missing records, then the selected records are displayed in the subform.

Comment: Ooooh. It displays them in the subform, and the user can then edit them? That doesn't actually fit my data model, but this is because I didn't explain it well. Again, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason SO won't let me edit my comment after a five minute pause. What I wanted to add: There is no limit of one record per date, so I need to be able to create records *even if one already exists for that date*. This form should never be used to modify or view existing data. Sorry to be unclear before.

Comment: What is your table structure? What is your primary key? Please edit your post, rather than add a comment.

Comment: While Remou's exact code didn't work for my application, I was able to fairly easily modify it to suit my needs once I learned enough VBA to parse it. Thanks, Remou.